# Tensorflow - wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2, AVX, AVX2, FMA

Tags: python, tensorflow, avx, python-3.6

I installed tensorflow from source code.

After installation when importing tensorflow on Python, it notify me of this.

```
>>> import tensorflow
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:125] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:125] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:125] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:125] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:125] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:95] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:95] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:95] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:95] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
```

it says SSE4.2, AVX, AVX2, and FMA are not compiled to use.

how can I solve this problem?